# JavaScript - multiple select dropdown list from string separated by new line

Tags: javascript, html, dropdownbox, multipleselection

I have a string 'y' coming from database Table separated by New line. I am trying to put string values in Multiple select drop down.
I tried below code but it did not work.
Could anyone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

```
var y = "50
60
70
80
90";
var x= y.split('');
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) 
{
  document.getElementById("names").options[i] = new Option(x[i], x[i]);
}

<select id="names" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Comment: Which bit are you actually stuck on?  Is the call to getElementById() not giving you what you want, or are you unable to add them to the dropdown?

Comment: Thanks a lots it's worked out for me

Answer (score 0):

y.split('') will retruns the array like this: ["50,60,70,80,90"] but what you want is this: ["50","60","70","80","90"]. You can refer the following code.

```
var y = "50 60 70 80 90";
var x = y.split(/\s+/);
var select = document.getElementById('names');

for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
   var opt = new Option(x[i], x[i]);
   select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "split(/\r|\n/)" instead of split('') to split string with new line characters.

```
var y = "50
60
70
80
90";
var x= y.split(/\r|\n/);
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) 
{
  document.getElementById("names").options[i] = new Option(x[i], x[i]);
}
```

View [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rge5nv3j/) for more information.